# When calling a method and assigning returned value to an array, why is C# using the array reference when method was called?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, return-value

I have the following C# program :

```
class Program
{ 
    static int[] foo = new int[1];

    static void Main()
    {
        foo[0] = Get();
        Console.WriteLine(foo[0]); //print "0"
    }

    static int Get()
    {
        foo = new int[1];
        return 5;
    }
}
```

After `Get()` has been called from `Main()`, I expect `foo` array to contains `5` at first position. However, it is zero. Why is it so ?

It is like C# captures a reference to `foo` when `Get()` method is called.
This old array reference is then used for assigning `Get()` returned value (and not the new one instantiated in `Get()`).

Comment: Your question already contains an answer to it.  There is no question left to answer.

Comment: Why such a design choice ? Is it implementation reason ? It spawned a bug in a project that took me a long time to find out, because for me, it's not expected behaviour.

Comment: I would question the design choice of modifying an array and returning the value to later be inserted into the same array variable.

Comment: If you want to know why Microsoft designed the language the way that they did then ask them, rather than asking SO.  Honestly I'd say that reading from and mutating the same variable at multiple points in the same statement is poor practice, precisely because it causes bugs like this.  You've written code that only works if the order of the expressions is evaluated in a very specific order, and you wrote it assuming that order was different from what it actually is.  You wrote code such that it depended on side effects to be observed *within the same statement* they were made.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *operands* in statements are always evaluated left to right, even if precedence rules for the *operators* deciding how things are then *processed* result in complex logic. This means that the `foo[0]` target is actually performed **before** the call to `Get`. You can see this in the IL:

```
.method private hidebysig static 
    void Main () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 25 (0x19)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldsfld int32[] Program::foo
    IL_0005: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0006: call int32 Program::Get()
    IL_000b: stelem.i4
    IL_000c: ldsfld int32[] Program::foo
    IL_0011: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0012: ldelem.i4
    IL_0013: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
    IL_0018: ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Note that the `ldsfld ... foo` and `ldc.i4.0` (the constant zero) are executed **before** the `call ... Get()`, with those values left on the stack for use in the later `ldsfld ... foo`. In more complicated cases (involving brackets etc), it can be very interesting to see the  tricks the compiler has used to retain left-to-right evaluation. Tools like sharplab can help with this; [here's your example in sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACAGAAhwEYBuAWACgqcAmI4gdioG8CqDOGA2AtAOxgBtALoEAZgHtJBALwF+cAO59BQ4iIrVKXHkQAsDABwAKAJQcuLS7s5TJQvGPkBxODHNbbXEgE4T9o4iZqQEAPRhAA4IAjAEAER48TYEAL5UKSS8sQRuHhY6Vim69nIKyqrCGl7eRIwEAKw1nOmUqUA===).

This is due to 12.4 Operators in the ECMA 334 specification:

> ### 12.4.1 General
>
> ...
>
> The order of evaluation of operators in an expression is determined by the precedence and associativity of the operators (§12.4.2).
>
> Operands in an expression are evaluated from left to right. *[Example:* In F(i) + G(i++) * H(i), method F is called using the old value of i, then method G is called with the old value of i, and, finally, method H is called with the new value of i. This is separate from and unrelated to operator precedence. *end example]*

Comment: But MSDN says assignment is evaluated from right to left. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx So is this a violation of the specification?

Comment: @Adrian I *think* that's talking about the order in which the *operator* is evaluated... not the *operands*. The *operator* when talking about assignment only *really* makes sense when there are multiple assignments, otherwise it is the final operator; but imagine: `bar.x = foo.y = z = 3;`; I would expect this to be evaluated in the order:`bar, foo, 3, z=, .y=, .x=`

Comment: @Adrian [Precedence, associativity , and the order of evaluation are all different things.](https://ericlippert.com/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order/)  In the page you linked it's very explicit that the order of evaluation is always left to right for everything.  Anything that's not left to right is referring to precedence or associativity.

Comment: @Adrian adding language spec reference; found it!

Comment: @Servy MSDN states itself : *evaluation proceeds according to the associativity of the operator, either from right to left or from left to right*

Comment: @Adrian the *operator* evaluates like that; but the *operands* are **always** left-to-right

Comment: @MarcGravell I see. Thank you :)

Comment: @Adrian Oh, you linked to the C specs, not the C# specs.  That'd be why.

Comment: @Servy even in C#, assignment is right-associative; this is 12.4.2 in ECMA 334 (just before it becomes 12.4.3); the key point is that it is the **operator** that is right-associative, but the *operands* in C# are always left-to-right

Comment: @MarcGravell But this isn't about associativity, it's about order of evaluation.  Adrian quoted a statement on MSDN saying that the two are the same, which apparently the case in C, but in C# associativity has nothing at all to do with order of evaluation, which is always strictly left to right.

Comment: @Servy also the c# 1.0 specs state *The assignment operators and the conditional operator (?:) are right-associative, meaning that operations are performed from right to left. For example, x = y = z is **evaluated** as x = (y = z).* It is about evaluation of the operators, not the operands, and this is the distinction. What I mean to say is, that the specs are not very specific what evaluation they actually mean.